# Passing a list of values from jsp to Action class in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, struts-tags

I have the following JSP code to display a list  of values

```jsp
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            Age
        </td>
        <td>
            Id
        </td>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="resultList">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name="Name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name="Age" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <s:textfield name="Id" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:submit action="finalSubmit" value=" Submit " />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Its displays a list of result. Now I want to pass all the Id values to the action class. I have defined the action name in `struts.xml`. Now in the action class only the last value of the Id is coming. But I need all the Ids in the action class.

Comment: The action should contain a list of objects, each with name, age, and id fields. I would recommend *against* naming properties with an uppercase letter as you've done here. The form fields should be named using list notation, e.g., `people[i].name`. See http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-AnadvancedexampleforindexedListsandMaps.

Answer (score 1):

In the action, that should be configured with the name `finalSubmit` create the property

```
List<Long> allIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
//create getter and setter
```

In the JSP rename the field that has `Id` value and add the iterator status attribute.

```
<s:iterator var="row" value="resultList" status="status">
  <s:textfield name="allIds[%{#status.index}]" value="%{#row.Id}"/>
```

upon submit all ids should come to the list above.